# Adding a new parameter to a Class which is instantiated by Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I have this class, which is part of a SpringBoot Application

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springboot.tutorial.upwork.service.WelcomeService;


@RestController
public class WelcomeController {

    @Autowired
    private WelcomeService service;

    // http://localhost:7777/welcome
    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return service.retrieveWelcomeMessage();
    }

    // http://localhost:7777/welcome/bla
    @RequestMapping("/welcome/{msg}")
    public String welcome(@PathVariable("msg") String message) {
        return service.retrieveWelcomeMessage(message);
    }

}
```

Now i need to add a variable to hold some data, which will be available to class methods. How can i do it since an instance of this class is created by Spring?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your exact scenario, but you can try using Environment variables, in that case you can read it using expression

Comment: create a static variable and get it where you want it and set it if you need to change any any point.. or if you can do it by Spring Cloud Config,